# primeng p-table filter with editable FormArray - FilterService Value getting null

Tags: angular, filter, formarray, tablecelleditor, p-table

I'm facing an issue while implementing filter on primeng p-table with formarray controls, Filter didn't work properly, So registered custom filter and tested then the value is null for all the rows, how can get control/value of the control to filter is custom filter.

Please find implementation at
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo-i44jxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with this issue and I found a solution which I will share. Just pass 'value.prop' to the property field, instead of just 'prop', e.g. field="value.code"

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo-7xlock?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html